# How i can call one function in click event of the <kendo-tabstrip-tab> component?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have this kendo-tabstrip-tab:

```
<kendo-tabstrip tabPosition="left">
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab (change)="test()" [title]="'Geral'" [selected]="true">
        <ng-template kendoTabContent>
              test
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

When i click in the kendo-tabstrip-tab i need to call the function `test()` that print the event in my ts component:

```
  test(event){
    console.log('i don't receive this console...')
  }
```

But when i click in kendo-tabstrip-tab no one event is being called. Don't have documentation of this component, only the parent component (kendo-tabstrip) and i need to call functions when kendo-tabstrip-tab is changed.

I also tried:

```
(click)="test()"
```

But it's not calling the function when i click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `@Output` defined on the [`TabStripTabComponent`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/TabStripTabComponent/), as you can read.

You should use the [`tabSelect`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/TabStripComponent/#toc-tabselect) event on the `TabStripComponent`, this will trigger an event which will contain the index number of the selected tab.

```
<kendo-tabstrip tabPosition="left" (tabSelect)="onSelectTab($event)">
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab (change)="test()" [title]="'Geral'" [selected]="true">
    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
      test
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

Comment: The event is called `tabSelect`, not `selectTab`. `selectTab` is a method of TabStripComponent that allows the selection of a tab programatically.

Comment: @Shai you are right, copied the wrong one :) I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/TabStripComponent/ `tabSelect` does what you need to do, it contains the `index` value of the tabs.

```
<kendo-tabstrip (tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">
    ...
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

where `onTabSelect($event)`

```
public onTabSelect(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8o5ff?file=app/app.component.ts